# Space shuttle Initial ADI frame Before Switch to LVLH?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, frames

The space shuttle crew switched the ADI frame to LVLH as soon as the roll maneuver was completed.

They waited for that time because the LVLH frame is in mathematical gimbal lock (singularity) when pitch is +- 90 deg.

But what frame was selected in the ADI before the LVLH switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was initially in REF.

Source: Ascent checklist switch list, p 9-4

https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/567068main_ASC_135_F_1.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Since REF could be changed, I wonder what that initial REF frame would have been aligned with. I imagine it would have been a convenient frame, maybe fixed to the launchpad, maybe aligned with the launch azimuth? And would it have been fixed to the launchpad (and therefore rotating with the earth) or would it have been inertial (and therefore not fixed to the launchpad except maybe at a specific time instant in the launch sequence)?

Comment: Check the SCOM but ISTR REF was an inertial frame. Can't recall what it was defined as prelaunch. SCOM might say.

Comment: SCOM says it's inertial and the reference is the nominal azimuth at liftoff (I assume at the nominal liftoff time). You might enjoy reading the part about manually flying ascents. It says the HSI is the primary cue for yaw - which might speak to your other question about pinning the ADI in yaw. But IANAP  (I am not a pilot)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! So REF points to launch azimuth at T0, and since it is inertial, it does not rotate with the earth or stay fixed to the launchpad. Plus, REF would be selected only until roll was completed and pitchover begun, at which point LVLH would normally take over. I think I got it?

Comment: So if the HDI was the primary reference for yaw, then it seems you could do without the LVLH yaw readout, especially if it was unreliable during launch... Now I'm wondering where the HDI got its yaw numbers, though. It seems it wasn't from the same quaternion/Euler-sequence pipeline the ADI's digital readout presumably got its numbers. I'll have to read up on the HSI, but could it have just pointed to magnetic North so that it wouldn't need all those calculations to begin with? Hm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that during ascent "North" on the HSI (the lubber line) was the target insertion plane. But again, IANAP and the SCOM has detailed writeups.

Comment: Oh really? Hah. The more you learn. It wouldn't have crossed my mind that North might not point north. I'm sure they had a good reason for it, but now I'll have to know. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Was the frame switch from REF to LVLH purely for ADI display? Or did they also swap the frame in which the pitchover and gravity turn attitude programs (and hence also the flight control errors) were calculated?

Comment: Just for ADI display. Also, I think the ADI only "came alive" 11 seconds before liftoff - often you could hear the crew say "nav init" - so the REF part only lasted a very few seconds.

Comment: Interesting! Do you know what frame the calculations themselves would have been based on? I want to say an inertial frame---maybe *the* inertial frame associated with the ADI INRTL switch position? And yet, wouldn't a pitch program be simplest in a local vertical frame, since then pitch would always be a rotation about a single axis?

Comment: Pretty sure the real calculations ("truth data") were done in inertial. Angles for displays were derived from that by various transformations.  Don't get too hung up on the ADI, it and its switches were only for crew display.

Comment: Sorry for the extended questions. I'll make this my last one: In the video you shared before of the space shuttle pitchover, what frame was the ADI set to? LVLH had a singularity at +- 90 deg pitch, but I read elsewhere that REF frames went by a pitch-yaw-roll rotation sequence, which would have given pitch a range of +-180 degrees, so that you wouldn't hit gimbal lock on a pitchover (so long as yaw was away from +-90 deg). Or would REF still be a bad choice for an orbital pitchover, since it is inertial (and therefore not reflective of the variable local vertical in orbit)?

Comment: Asking because I'm simulating a flipover and struggling with my roll-pitch-yaw attitude display. With a roll-pitch-yaw or yaw-pitch-roll sequence, pitch is limited to +- 90 deg, which is trouble if you're rotating 180+ degrees. But with a pitch-yaw-roll sequence, the pitch range is extended to +-180 degrees, so you can display your attitude angles without hitting or crossing gimbal lock if yaw stays near zero. I'm inclined to do this for my simulation, but I don't know these things well, and if it made sense, I suppose they would have done it in the shuttle?

Comment: @a1ex re: "the video you shared before of the space shuttle pitchover, what frame was the ADI set to? "  I would *like* to think that during that run back in 1991 I took the switch to LVLH, but I'd be lying if I said I could remember. I reviewed the uncut video but there was never a clear shot of the switches.

Comment: LVLH would make sense for that video because I noticed what looked liked gimbal lock. I'd feel extra confident in my flipover simulation if common practice for the space shuttle were to set the ADI frame to REF, I guess. Maybe. Because at 7,800 m/s, an inertial REF frame would diverge from a local vertical frame in seconds, so the pitch displayed to the crew would not be the intuitive number you'd expect (it's easy to think of pitch relative to local vertical but how would you visualize relative to some frame now at a small unknown angle to the local vertical? I'd struggle to visualize that).

Comment: So on the one hand, the pitch-yaw-roll order associated with the REF frame would prevent gimbal lock on the ADI display. But on the other hand, because REF is inertial, the angles displayed wouldn't be relative to local vertical and so they wouldn't be intuitive to the crew. LVLH would cause the display to hickup at +-90 degrees during pitchover, but when away from gimbal lock, the numbers displayed would be relative to local vertical and therefore perfectly intuitive. I think I'd pick LVLH too.

Comment: But it seems LVLH with pitch-yaw-roll sequence would give you the best of both worlds: intuitive pitch angle relative to local vertical *without* hickup at gimbal lock. I'm sure they managed just fine without this, but LVLH + pitch-yaw-roll order sort of seems ideal.